# How do I find the displacement of a particle at a given instant when the initial speed is not given?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, kinematics

The problem is as follows:

> A particle is moving along a straight line at a constant acceleration
>   of $3 \frac{m}{s^{2}}$. If it is known that an instant of $t=4\,s$ its
>   displacement is $100\,m$. If is also known when $t=6\,s$ its speed is
>   $15\,\frac{m}{s}$. What will be its displacement on that instant?.

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{128 m}\\
2.&\textrm{130 m}\\
3.&\textrm{144 m}\\
4.&\textrm{124 m}\\
5.&\textrm{152 m}
\end{array}$

For this particular problem I attempted to use the motion equation as follows:

$x(t)=x_{o}+v_{ox}t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$

Then I thought that the reference point would be $x_{o}=0$ and from the given conditions ($t=4$, $x=100$, $a=3$) it could be found the initial speed as follows:

$x(t)=0+v_{ox}t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$

$x(t)=x_{o}+v_{ox}t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$

$100=x(4)=4v_{ox}+ \frac{3\times 4 \times 4}{2}$

$100=4v_{ox}+ \frac{3\times 4 \times 4}{2}$

$25=v_{ox}+ 6$

$v_{ox}=19$

Using this known speed and the other known speed as $15 \frac{m}{s}$ and the elapsed time between the two I could calculate the "acceleration" for that given period.

I assumed that it was during this part the object is slowing down or deccelerate hence $a$ would be negative.
(Note: For the sake of brevity and understanding I´m omitting the units but all are accordingly and consisten)

$v_{f}=v_{o}+at$

$v_{f}=19+3(4)=31$

$15=31+a(2)$

$a=\frac{15-31}{2}=-8$

$v_{f}^{2}=v_{o}^{2}+2a\Delta x$

$\left(15\right)^{2}=\left(31\right)^{2}+2(-8)\Delta x$

$2(-8)\Delta x = 225-961 = 736$

$\Delta x = 46$

Therefore wouldn't its displacement to that instant be $100+46= 146\,m$.

However this answer does not appear in the alternatives. What could I be possibly doing wrong?. Can somebody guide me?.

I tried to look this question in different ways and still I can't get to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it has a constant acceleration of $3\frac{m}{s}$ and reaches a speed of $15\frac{m}{s}$ after $6$ seconds, then its initial speed $v_0$ at four seconds was $9\frac{m}{s}$.

To find the displacement, use the equation $\Delta x= v_0t +\frac{1}{2}at^2.$ And so its displacement at $6$ seconds should be $100+(9(2)+\frac{1}{2}\cdot3\cdot 2^2)=124$ m.

Comment: But how do I exactly get to that answer?. This is why I shown the steps I attempted using the position equation. Why I can't obtain that speed from there?.

Comment: I did noted your edit but it still doesn't address my problem which is exactly on what part of my assumptions did I made a mistake.

Comment: In other words why I cannot obtain the initial speed $v_{o}=9$ from the position equation.

Comment: Then what should had been changed there to get to $9$ or it cannot be found given that information?

Comment: Okay If I use the conditions you mention then what. I mean $x(6)=?$ ?

Comment: Okay never mind. Why did you want to use that equation when you could've used the much simpler equation $v=v_0+at$ which is what I used? There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Because this problem was intended to be solved using functions and I asked that approach, hence how to solve with thar route. However how did you used the final and initial speed equation to get to $9$?.

Comment: Perhaps do you refer to $15=v_{o}+(3\times2)$?.

Comment: I do understand that part. But I'd like to know if there was another route to get to the same result as it turns out that so far now the only method that I can use to solve this is by following your recipe.

Comment: I mean, you can't assume the reference point at $t=0$ is $0$, so I don't know if there's another efficient way.